# accessing a child class prop from parent

Tags: php, oop

I mean something like that:

```
class parentClass {
    public function method() {
        echo $this->prop;
    }
}
class childClass extends parentClass {
    public $prop = 5;
}
```

How can I get a child prop from the parent prop?

Thanks...

Comment: Practically - parent class should know nothing about its children. You better explained *why* you need that, because there is a chance you're solving the issue in a wrong way

Comment: Since a parent class is supposed to be agnostic about its child classes, this is not possible (without some pretty ugly finagling). Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish? There is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: This exact code snippet works perfectly. PHP does not use classic polymorphism because it know the runtime class of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I don't fully understand what you want or the solution is as trivial as the following code.

```
class parentClass {
    public function method() {
        echo $this->prop;
    }
}
class childClass extends parentClass {
    public $prop = 5;
}
$object = new childClass();
$object->method();
```

I mean the child class is extending the base class which means it will also inherit all the methods of its parent's class. That makes the whole process of using the parent's class method as simple as calling it from the instance of the child class.

Answer (score 1):

All protected and public members of child classes are visible from within their parent class in PHP, so the example code you provided should work just fine. [Quote from the php doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

But the actual question is: do you really need it?

The proper OO way would be to define a self-contained parent class that expresses something. It should not *need* to access properties of child classes - this is a so-called [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). If you really think that you have a case where a similar construct is necessary, you are probably looking for abstract methods, which guarantee that *every* child class has this property:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public function makeNoise() {
        echo $this->getNoiseString();
    }
    protected abstract function getNoiseString();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    protected function getNoiseString() {
        return 'meow';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//parent
class parentClass {

    protected $prop = null;

    public function method() {
        echo $this->prop;
    }
}

//child
class childClass extends parentClass {
    protected $prop = 5;
}
```

Make sure the variable is defined in the parentclass as well. So it will be accessible by the parent.